# Dynamic group by with case statement in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

I'm building a report in my rails app and now I'm stuck with the complexity of my group_by. This report consists basically in show the info of a Customer grouped by name, birth_date, age, client_type (enumerize 1 - Normal, 2 - VIP, 3 - With restrictions), gender (enumerize 1 - Male, 2 - Female), create_at. Today my code is like this.

```
@customers = Customers.where(filters).group_by{ |customer|
     case params[:grouped_by].to_i
     when 0
         customer.name
     when 1
         customer.birth_date.try(:to_date)
     when 2
         customer.age
     when 3
         customer.client_type.try(:text)
     when 4
         customer.gender.try(:text)
     else
         customer.created_at.try(:to_date)
     end
     }
```

Well, this piece of code isn't pretty and I have no ideas what to do. I tried to used the rails send but without success, just because of the try. And i don't want to use ActiveRecord.group.

I know that this question is too much scholar, but I out of approaches and any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: you can use a hash with the processing info, but it won't be much more clear. Other than indentation, do/end instead of {}, and moving `params[:grouped_by].to_i` out of the block (since it's constant), your code looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried and not sure,please create one hash like

```
1.9.3p448 :062 > hash={0=>{:name => :to_s},1 => {:birth_date => :to_date}}
```

then

```
1.9.3p448 :067 > case q
1.9.3p448 :068?>   when 0,1
1.9.3p448 :069?>   aa=Site.try(hash[q].keys.first).try(hash[q].values.first)
1.9.3p448 :070?>   puts aa
1.9.3p448 :071?>   end
```

Please try like that.if it's worked means fine.

Comment: Kingston, excuse me for the delay, yes your approach helped me to find a way. Instead of create a hash, I used a array.